# estas dos expresiones son equivalentes en python?

Tags: python, condiciones

Tengo estas dos expresiones en un programa de Python pero la segunda no me esta arrojando el mismo resultado de la primera y se supone que deberian ser equivalentes y no encuentro el error.

`if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0`

`if not year % 100 != 0 and year % 400 == 0:`

Les adjunto el codigo completo

````
def es_bisiesto(year):
    if not year % 4 == 0:
        return False
    
    if not year % 100 != 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        return False

    return True 

#pedir datos
dia = int(input("Dia: "))
mes = int(input("Mes: "))
anyo = int(input("Año: "))


#comprobar bisiesto

if not es_bisiesto(anyo):
    dias[1] = 28

#contar los dias de meses anteriores
contador_dias = 0
compara_mes = 0

while compara_mes < mes - 1:
    contador_dias += dias[compara_mes]
    compara_mes += 1
    
contador_dias += dia

print("El dia es:", contador_dias)```
````

Answer (score 0):

La expresión

```
not (a and b)
```

es equivalente a

```
(not a or not b)
```

que es lo que (casi) tienes como segunda expresión en la pregunta. Por tanto, para hacerla equivalente a la primera volvemos a negarla:

```
a and b == not (not a or not b)
```

En resumen, dados

```
if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0: 

if not year % 100 != 0 and year % 400 == 0:
```

las expresiones equivalentes son

```
if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0: 

if not (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
```

donde las negaciones han sido incorporadas en las comparaciones para simplificar.

#### Demo

```
print("a b c d")
for a in [0, 1]:
    for b in [0, 1]:
        c = a and b;
        d = not (not a or not b);
        print(a, b, c, d)
```

produce la tabla de verdad para ambas expresiones:

```
a b c d
0 0 0 False
0 1 0 False
1 0 0 False
1 1 1 True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: La programación utiliza la tabla de verdad, y parece que esto es llamado [leyes de morgan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyes_de_De_Morgan)